# Why does SQcircuits give 0 as the quasiparticle decoherence rates for a transmon qubit?

Tags: simulation, decoherence

I am a high schooler new to quantum computing and for my project I use SQcircuits to simulate the T1 of a transmon. However, looking through some literature, it seems that quasiparticle noise is applicable to a transmon, yet SQcircuits gives no value for it. I would like to inquire why this is the case. Thank you.